# How do I find the declared fields of a field?

Tags: java, reflection

So, I have this function:

```
public Object findObject(Object object, String name) {
    if (object == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for (Field foundField : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (foundField.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            try {
                return foundField.get(object);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                ClientImpl.getInstance().getUtil().addChatMessage(ClientImpl.getInstance().getLogo() + "Invalid argument.");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                ClientImpl.getInstance().getUtil().addChatMessage(ClientImpl.getInstance().getLogo() + "Invalid argument.");
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So that will return all the declared fields of an object and it's super class, I have this loop:

```
        objectName = objectName.replace("main/", "");
        String[] split = objectName.split("/");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            object = this.findObject(object, split[i]);
        }
```

The inital object is a class, let's say that class is called `Main`.

I'd input something like this:

```
main/gameWorld/gameData
```

It would search the inital object for any fields called `gameWorld`, once found it would set the current object to `gameWorld` and search that object for any fields called `gameData`. This works, if I input something like this:

```
main/gameWorld
```

but if I do

```
main/gameWorld/gameData
```

It claims that object is `null`.

Comment: You're overwriting `object`.

Comment: Yes, I don't see how that is a problem, though?

Comment: Let's see your classes. That will clear and it up.

Comment: Yep, a nice [SCCEE](http://sscce.org/) would make the job much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might in that you're not querying fields in a superclass, so the field `gameData` is not found. From JavaDoc for `getDeclaredFields`:

> Returns an array of `Field` objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this`Class` object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, **but excludes inherited fields**.

So if your `GameWorld` containing `gameData` is inherited from a superclass with this field, i.e.

```
class AbstractGameWorld{
     GameData gameData;
}

class GameWorld extends AbstractGameWorld{
     ...
}
```

This would be the case.

Comment: I'm confused. I know it excludes inherited fields, which is why I advance up the super classes checking their fields until there is no super class.

Comment: I am sorry, I only glanced in search for a `Class.getSuperclass` method and didn't find it. Could you point me to the place where you get the superclass?

Comment: Ah sorry, It is my fault, I just realized it is my other method that I used for getting fields that goes through the super classes, I just forgot to include it in the new one I created. It should work now. Thank you, you have been a massive help and I probably would have never fixed it otherwise. Thanks again.